# simple form duplicate input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm using ruby simple_form to generate a form with a checkbox in it. The form is rendered with:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :receive_notifications, as: :boolean, label: 'Receive Notifications' %>
<% end %>
```

This outputs the html:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/users/9" class="simple_form edit_user" id="edit_user_9" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div style="display:none">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="m2rM8t/lZ1g3UfYER4xFiNkHKpDX5GrpjdapQCLPKHQ=">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group boolean optional user_receive_notifications">
    <input name="user[receive_notifications]" type="hidden" value="0">
    <label class="boolean optional control-label checkbox" for="receive_notifications">
      <input checked="checked" class="boolean optional" id="user_receive_notifications" name="user[receive_notifications]" type="checkbox" value="1">Receive Notifications
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

The question is, how do I get rid of that duplicate input inside the form-group?

Edit:
Form Data from browser inspector:

utf8:✓

_method:patch

authenticity_token:m2rM8t/lZ1g3UfYER4xFiNkHKpDX5GrpjdapQCLPKHQ=

user[receive_notifications]:0

user[receive_notifications]:1

Answer (score 0):

You don't and you shouldn't. That is a hidden value that is there to fix a problem with the way that browsers do checkboxes that aren't filled in.

The problem is this: if you have only the one (visible) checkbox, and then you don't click it... html will not send a value for that checkbox at all.

This is not what you want... what you want is if a user does not click a checkbox, that you receive the value:  `:user_receive_notifications => false`

So this is the way that Rails has hacked html to always send that value if the checkbox is present on the page, but not checked.

Comment: My form is submitting 2 fields with differing values with the same name.

Comment: right... then you have a problem, but believe me - that hidden field is not what's causing that problem. So, lets have a look at the rest of the form?

Comment: Also - why don't you show us an example of the data that you are receiving while you're at it :) Note: don't you're new here, so I should say: don't put code in comments (like here), because the formatting is truly awful. You should edit your question and put the code there.